# Vector Tiles API Mapbox

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dictionary, mapbox

after I am upgrade libray **@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps 8.1.0** to **@rnmapbox/maps 10.0.7** in the invoice notice the new charge **Vector Tiles API**.
my code like this:

```
const ACCESS_TOKEN = '';
Mapbox.setWellKnownTileServer('Mapbox');
Mapbox.setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
Platform.OS === 'android' && Mapbox.setConnected(true);


return (
        <MapView
          ref={ref => (this.mapRef = ref)}
          {...mapboxProps}
          style={styles.container}
          zoomLevel={18}
          pitch={60}
          attributionEnabled={false}
          logoEnabled={false}
          scaleBarEnabled={false}
          surfaceView={true}
          compassEnabled={false}
          onDidFinishRenderingMapFully={() => this.handleFollowUserLocation()}
        >
          <Camera
            ref={c => (this.camera = c)}
            defaultSettings={{ zoomLevel: 18 }}
            zoomLevel={18}
            followUserMode={Mapbox.UserTrackingMode.Follow}
            followPitch={60}
            animationMode="none"
            followUserLocation={true}
            followZoomLevel={18}
            centerCoordinate={mapboxProps.centerCoordinate}
          />
          <UserLocation
            minDisplacement={1}
            onUpdate={location => this.handleFollowUserLocation(location)}
            visible={true}
            showsUserHeadingIndicator={false}
          />
        </MapView>
)
```

how can I reduce the call to the vector tiles? or any suggestion?